# Calibrate routes not lining up with calibration points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, route, z-value, m-values

I am currently building a model that calibrates Z and M values from Cross Sections for a stream. Z being the 100yr flood and M being the station number.  What's happening is the vertex on the stream where the cross section intersects does not contain the 100yr flood and station number of that cross section.  For the picture below, the red is the true value of the cross section and the blue is where the cross section value should be.

[image]

Comment: Don't know if this is related but all your XY values are almost the all the same, I'm guessing its in lat/long? Try projecting your data into a coordinate system in metres then do your MZ analysis?

Comment: So are you saying the M value of the cross-section doesn't match the M value of the vertex that has been interpolated from adjacent vertices M values?  If so, in that case I think you should re-state your question ... perhaps: how to *re*calibrate the M values of a polyline using M values from a (presumably more accurate) cross-sectional profile?

Comment: Turns out the projection was the issue.  Thanks for the help!